# Is running each SQL-query in a separate thread (during startup) bad practise?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, multithreading, thread-safety

My Java application will need to gather information from different MySQL-tables on startup. Without the database information, the application cannot be used. Hence, **it takes up to a few seconds to start up** (reducing this time with cache when possible).

1. **Would it be bad practise to preform each of these SQL-queries in a
   separate thread**, allowing computers with multiple CPU cores to start
   the application eventually even faster (no guarantees, I know)?
2. **Is there any cons that I need to know about before implementing this
   "system"?**

Comment: "allowing computers with multiple CPU cores to start the application eventually even faster" --- the slowest part there is network IO and DBMS server itself, not client's CPU

Comment: @zerkms Sure, but allowing the client to eventually execute several queries at once should reduce the overall startup time of the application?

Comment: I am greatly interested what kind of data it is you need to sync before your application starts completely. Because your application can't start at all if the database is offline. I'd suggest using a "use old data" caching approach were your application checks if db is online, if so, startup with old data and then steadily pull fresh data from the DB and showing some kind of green statusline after doing so like "everything is up to date". this of course depends on the data used

Comment: @Najzero You're right. I'm going to approach a similar solution, but at some point (most likely the first run), some core data WILL need to be fetched before the app. can be used. The application itself will require access to the database to be able to fulfill its purpose anyhow; but still.

Comment: I'd suggest trying to pull as much data in one query as possible then. Not that I saying you should not usemultible threads for fetching data from a DB, it just could make more headaches than 5 seconds of waiting time (maybe display a random funny startup-sequence  http://web.mit.edu/campus-map/please-wait/ :-) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's something your going to have to try.

If your bringing back relatively few rows from each table, it would probably take longer to establish the database connections in each of the threads (or jdbc connection pool) than to establish it once and do the queries.

Fortunately it's not a lot of code, so you should be able to try it out pretty quickly.

Answer (score 1):

No, certainly not. For example, a Java web server like Tomcat makes it all the time, when multiple users access your web application concurrently.

Just make sure you manage properly your data integrity using transactions.

Answer (score 1):

Executing the request by parallelizing them instead of executing them serially may be a good idea.

Take care to use a Datasource and each request must use its own connection to the database (never share a conenction between different threads simultaneously).

Answer (score 1):

Be sure that your connection pool and your thread pool size is well adapted

Answer (score 1):

Database sessions are relatively expensive objects.  Parallelizing to a few threads is no problem, but don't create 1000 threads if you have 1000 tables.

Furthermore, multithreading comes with complexity and potentially huge maintenance costs (for example, unreproducible issues resulting from race conditions).  So, do your measurements, and if you find out that the speed up is just a few percent, just put everything back.

There are more ways to avoid the latency you see.  For example, you can send multiple queries in a single command batch, thus reducing the number of roundtrips between your code and the database.